# Is it a good idea to have a single database per user in a Forms Authentication environment, instead of a single multi-tenant database?

Tags: sql-server, database, forms-authentication, multi-tenant

I've been contemplating this back and forth - right now, I have an app with many users, and each record in the database is tied to the user's authenticated username (by the `CreatedBy` column).  I know this is a common practice for differentiating user records.  But, I've been thinking in terms of keeping the records as secure as possible (so that no other user can access them by SQL injection, XSS, etc.) would a good idea be to create a separate database for each user?  This would obviously mean if I have 150 users, I'll have 150 databases.  Is this generally a bad practice?  Is containing each user's records in the same database acceptable when it comes to security of the individual's records so as long as I prevent SQL injection and XSS?

Comment: 150 doesn't sound like a lot. What about when you have 1500 users? 15000? A separate database for every user simply doesn't scale.

Comment: Maybe [this discussion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) helps

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric put that as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: I would suggest that you decide the scaling factor by tenants than by users. That will  make more sense so that you can scale out a tenant that has a higher usage than the rest.